# How to generate unique(!) arrays/lists/sequences of uniformly distributed random

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

Let‘s say I generate a pack, i.e., a one dimensional array of 10 random numbers with a random generator. Then I generate another array of 10 random numbers. I do this X times. How can I generate unique arrays, that even after a trillion generations, there is no array which is equal to another?

In one array, the elements can be duplicates. The array just has to differ from the other arrays with at least one different element from all its elements.

Is there any numpy method for this? Is there some special algorithm which works differently by exploring some space for the random generation? I don’t know.

One easy answer would be to write the arrays to a file and check if they were generated already, but the I/O operations on a subsequently bigger file needs way too much time.

Comment: Do you want to try some strategy that somehow ensures the "next" pack will never have been seen before, or one that tests a potential pack against all other prior packs to see if there is a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult request, since one of the properties of a RNG is that it *should* repeat sequences randomly.

You also have the problem of trying to record terabytes of prior results.  Once thing you *could* try is to form a hash table (for search speed) of the existing arrays.  Using this depends heavily on whether you have sufficient RAM to hold the entire list.

If not, you might consider disk-mapping a fast search structure of some sort.  For instance, you could implement an on-disk binary tree of hash keys, re-balancing whenever you double the size of the tree (with insertions).  This lets you keep the file open and find entries via `seek`, rather than needing to represent the full file in memory.

You could also maintain an in-memory index to the table, using that to drive your `seek` to the proper file section, then reading only a small subset of the file for the final search.

Does that help focus your implementation?

Comment: Yes it does help, THANKS. I have terabytes of RAM and with my other limitations on my simulations, it wouldn't be the limiting factor and I would reach my combination count before. I have to look all of it up, to pragmatically try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the 10 numbers in a pack are each in the range [0..max].  Each pack can then be considered as a 10 digit number in base max+1.  Obviously, the size of max determines how many unique packs there are.  For example, if max=9 there are 10,000,000,000 possible unique packs from [0000000000] to [9999999999].

The problem then comes down to generating unique numbers in the correct range.

Given your "trillions" then the best way to generate guaranteed unique numbers in the range is probably to use an encryption with the correct size output.  Unless you want 64 bit (DES) or 128 bit (AES) output then you will need some sort of format preserving encryption to get output in the range you want.

For input, just encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... in turn.  Encryption guarantees that, given the same key, the output is unique for each unique input.  You just need to keep track of how far you have got with the input numbers.  Given that, you can generate more unique packs as needed, within the limit imposed by max.  After that point the output will start repeating.

Obviously as a final step you need to convert the encryption output to a 10 digit base max+1 number and put it into an array.

Comment: thanks for your response! I am not into encryption that much but I try to look it up.

Comment: It is not for security, but for the uniqueness property.  It saves having to record what random numbers you have generated so far.  See [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) for some more details. For your purposes cycle walking should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Important caveat:**

This will not allow you to generate "arbitrarily" many unique packs. Please see limits as highlighted by @Prune.

Note that as the number of requested packs approaches the number of unique packs this takes longer and longer to find a pack. I also put in a safety so that after a certain number of tries it just gives up.

Feel free to adjust:

```
import random

## -----------------------
## Build a unique pack generator
## -----------------------
def build_pack_generator(pack_length, min_value, max_value, max_attempts):
    existing_packs = set()

    def _generator():
        pack = tuple(random.randint(min_value, max_value) for _ in range(1, pack_length +1))
        pack_hash = hash(pack)

        attempts = 1
        while pack_hash in existing_packs:
            if attempts >= max_attempts:
                raise KeyError("Unable to fine a valid pack")
            pack = tuple(random.randint(min_value, max_value) for _ in range(1, pack_length +1))
            pack_hash = hash(pack)
            attempts += 1

        existing_packs.add(pack_hash)
        return list(pack)

    return _generator

generate_unique_pack = build_pack_generator(2, 1, 9, 1000)
## -----------------------

for _ in range(50):
    print(generate_unique_pack())
```

Comment: Yes, given enough RAM to hold `existing_packs`, this is the implementation I had in mind: `set` uses a hash on non-trivial keys.

Answer (score 0):

The [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) suggests that at some point you don't need to bother checking for duplicates.  For example, if each value in a 10 element "pack" can take on more than ~250 values then you only have a 50% chance of seeing a duplicate after generating 1e12 packs.  The more distinct values each element can take on the lower this probability.

You've not specified what these random values are in this question (other than being uniformly distributed) but your linked question suggests they are Python `float`s.  Hence each number has `2**53` distinct values it can take on, and the resulting probability of seeing a duplicate is practically zero.

There are a few ways of rearranging this calculation:

1. for a given amount of state and number of iterations what's the probability of seeing at least one collision
2. for a given amount of state how many iterations can you generate to stay below a given probability of seeing at least one collision
3. for a given number of iterations and probability of seeing a collision, what state size is required

The below Python code calculates option 3 as it seems closest to your question.  The other options are available on the [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) page.

```
from math import log2, log1p

def birthday_state_size(size, p):
    # -log1p(p) is a numerically stable version of log(1/(1+p))
    return size**2 / (2*-log1p(-p))

log2(birthday_state_size(1e12, 1e-6)) # => ~100
```

So as long as you have more than 100 uniform bits of state in each pack everything should be fine.  For example, two or more Python floats is OK (`2 * 53`), as is 10 integers with >= 1000 distinct values (`10*log2(1000)`).

You can of course reduce the probability down even further, but as noted in the Wikipedia article going below 1e-15 quickly approaches the reliability of a computer. This is why I say "practically zero" given the 530 bits of state provided by 10 uniformly distributed floats.